# Convert SQLServer Query to SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

Below is my SQL Server query which I want to Convert it into SQLite
Is there any online toll available to convert sql query into SQLite

```
select variable_col,
    timecomes_col,
    lead(timegoes_col, 1, 0) over (
        order by variable_col
        ) as timegoes
from Table1
```

Comment: Try it yourself - run the query against your SQLite database, review any error(s) that come back, fix, repeat.

Comment: Getting error as near "(": syntax error:

Comment: sqlite doesnt support window functions. You'll need to provide more info, same data and expected output

Comment: `Lead` is one of Unsupported Sql Analytical Functions, check [here] (http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions)

Comment: I know SQLite doesn't support analytic functions but how can I replace this query into SQLite

Comment: What can I use instead of Lead in SQLite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a SQLite view where a row depends on the previous row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003313/create-a-sqlite-view-where-a-row-depends-on-the-previous-row)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829514/sqlite-query-to-group-columns this is what I want

Comment: Please post the table schema. It may be possible to emulate the same effect efficiently eg with a self join and a check that ROWID of the left table  = (ROWID - 1) on the right table

Comment: Above link have schema and well as dummy data to replicate the scenario sir

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the MSSQL LEAD in MSSQL of your query:

```
SELECT VARIABLE_COL
    ,TIMECOMES_COL
    ,LEAD(TIMEGOES_COL, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY VARIABLE_COL) AS TIMEGOES
FROM TABLE1
;
```

without using ANALITYCS FUNCTIONS:

```
    SELECT VARIABLE_COL
        ,TIMECOMES_COL
        ,LEAD(TIMEGOES_COL, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY VARIABLE_COL) AS TIMEGOES /* this is here to compare values*/
        , (SELECT TOP 1 TIMEGOES_COL FROM TABLE1 T2 WHERE TABLE1.TIMEGOES_COL < T2.TIMEGOES_COL ORDER BY T2.VARIABLE_COL) AS TIMEGOES_SUCC
FROM TABLE1
    ;
```

In sqlite should be:

```
SELECT VARIABLE_COL
            ,TIMECOMES_COL              
            , (SELECT  TIMEGOES_COL FROM TABLE1 T2 WHERE TABLE1.TIMEGOES_COL < T2.TIMEGOES_COL ORDER BY T2.VARIABLE_COL LIMIT 1) AS TIMEGOES_SUCC
    FROM TABLE1
        ;
```

As Panagiotis correctly suggested, this could cause a degradation in performances (particularly for a medium - large data table)

Comment: The performance of this will be *very* bad. The subquery will have to run once for each row of `TABLE1`

Comment: LEAD Function not there in SQLite @etsa

Comment: Yes, I made an error of copy-paste in the last query